# How to make bunch of html disappear or gone when on login path

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div>
    <span class="navbar"></span>
  <a class="dropdown">
  Bunch html
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var current_url = window.location.pathname;
if(current_url.indexOf('/login') === 0){
  var login = $('.navbar').next('.Dropdown');
  login.remove();
}
```

when on /login or /login/stuff, the whole html in dropdown should be removed.
But when I tested on local, it removed alright - a bit issue is when I refresh or go to that /login page, dropdown html will show up quickly and then disappear. It is not what i want. It should disappear totally when on /login page. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the things reversely,

CSS:

```
.navbar + a.dropdown { display:none; }
```

JS:

```
var current_url = window.location.pathname;
var login = $('.navbar').next('.Dropdown');

if(current_url.indexOf('/login') === 0){    
  login.remove();
} else {
  login.show();
}
```

Comment: I know but it still doesnt show anything keep on showing the html bunch then disappear.

Comment: I commented out JS. Login at top still display. I tested css with background: red and it s still showing even though display: none. weird

Comment: @joe Is that site live..? can i have a look..?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the Following.

1. First hide the anchor tag when initially loading.

   .dropdown {
       display:none; 
   }
2. Then do your thing in JQuery I did some change. For your Convenience.

   var current_url = window.location.pathname;
   var login = $('.navbar').next('.Dropdown');
   if(current_url.indexOf('/login') === 0){
     login.remove();
   }
3. After that you have to check whether you are in the login path and if not show the dropdown you can add it to the Else part.

   else {
     login.show();
   }